# Could reading & writing int which is declared with volatile and stored on a aligned address be garanteed to be atomic?

Tags: c++, data-race

Here the related [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/vbxMWfcTj):

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

#ifdef NO_STUCK_WITH_OPTIMIZATION 
using TYPE = std::atomic<int>;
#else
using TYPE = volatile int;  //The progrom seems not get stuck if the optimization is enabled.
#endif

int main()
{
    TYPE is_run{1}; //If the is_run is declared as volatile, then the program would never get stuck?
    auto thread = std::thread([&is_run](){while(1==is_run){
                                        }
        std::cout << "thread game over" << std::endl;
    });

    is_run = 0;
    thread.join();
}
```

***Question***: Could reading & writing int which is declared with `volatile` and stored on a aligned address be garanteed to be atomic? Or the conclusion is right just on [X86 platform](https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/is-int-write-operation-atomic-on-x86_64/)?

Somebody told me not to use `volatile`. This keyword was added before C++ had a memory model. It will make some issues go away (by preventing some compiler optimization), but not all and your code would still have UB.

And somebody told me that [it's atomic on any platform](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54292708#54292708).

I found some posts on SO, but the posts were updated more than 10 years ago. For example:

[ARM: Is writing/reading from int atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399026/arm-is-writing-reading-from-int-atomic). [^1]

[Are C++ Reads and Writes of an int Atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic). [^2]

**UPDATED**:
And as per (this post)[https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/is-int-write-operation-atomic-on-x86_64/] [^3], which says that:

> Nearly always we read from documents and web posts that X86_64 can do 64bits write operation atomically.
> So if thread 1 is writing value A to an integer while thread 2 is writing value B to the same integer we are guaranteed to observe either value A or value B and never anything in between, ignoring initial value of course.

**It seems that the posts (marked with [^1] [^2] [^3]) all says that it's atomic.**

And now I am really confused now.Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: The person who told you to avoid `volatile` for dealing with multithreading issues was correct -- the semantics of `volatile` aren't sufficiently strong to be useful for atomic operations.  If you want atomic integers in C++, `std::atomic` is the correct tool for the job.

Comment: `volatile` does not ensure synchronization between threads. It only treats the (single thread) access of that variable as a visible side effect for purposes of optimization.

Comment: @JohnFilleau If the side effect of the variable is guaranteed to be seen by the other thread, it does not mean reading&writing is atomic? Why? Could you please explain that in more details for me?

Comment: @John `volatile` doesn't protect the memory.  If two threads write to a volatile variable, that is a data race and undefined behavior.  The standard requires you use a synchronization technique, and `volatile` is not amongst those techniques.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the code snippet gets stuck when optimization is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726178/why-the-code-snippet-gets-stuck-when-optimization-is-enabled)

Comment: Every book on threading in c++ tells you how to do what you want.   And they all say that volatile doesn't do what you want.   So just follow the instructions from the experts.

Comment: "Could reading & writing int which is declared with volatile and stored on a aligned address be guaranteed to be atomic?" --> No.  To guarantee atomic access, qualify with `atomic` or prohibit interruption of the process/thread with implementation specific code.

Comment: @John everybody told you  to stay clear of `volatile`. It's also in the comments of your first question. I realize there's difference between the two, but for a Q&A site like SO, we must be very crisp and concise. Your edit to the 1st question was the right way to go. A second question is too much.

Comment: @ NathanOliver  Thank you.  Please see the updated question.

Comment: @John there's also a communication issue. The three questions you linked use the wording "atomic" but they don't refer to `std::atomic`, I think that feeds your confusion

Comment: @Jeffrey How do you understand the wording "atomic" in the aforementioned posts? My mother language is not English.

Comment: @John they mean atomic in the architecture / processor sense -- an action that cannot be preempted.